# Rollback SQL Server from code

Tags: sql-server, delphi

Guess my problem is pretty much popular, like [INFORMIX DB ROLLBACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978965/rollback-informix-database) we are developing long running algorithms on our database using DELPHI and SQL Server. If these programs fail we need to set our database back to the initial state. Go on the server side and detach the the database, restore the old database from a backup and the start again with our program tests. Long and time consuming procedure.

Can I set a savepoint in the database using Delphi and restore the DB from Delphi if my test failed ?

Comment: couldn't you run queries in batches and commit them? I once had to do something like this but this was replicating about 20 million records. So what I did was read them in blocks, did what was needed and did a multiple insert and then went on to the next block. The only extra thing is that you need to identify the last inserted records and this can be done using a simple comparison. Perhaps there's something else but is this workable for you?

Comment: If you use `TADOConnection` in Delphi, you could do: `ADOConnection.BeginTrans; <your-Delphi-db-procedure>; ADOConnection.CommitTrans;`. on exception: `ADOConnection.RollbackTrans`.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily use SQL Server's [Database Snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx) feature for this:

- create a database snapshot before you start (using `CREATE DATABASE snapshot_name.... AS SNAPSHOT OF database_name`)
- run your application
- if it fails, just restore from that snapshot (using `RESTORE DATABASE .... FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = '....'`)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. from the docs: `As the source database is updated, the database snapshot is updated.`. is that true?

Comment: @kobik: I share your confusion - seems to totally contradict the *A database snapshot is a read-only, static view of a SQL Server database (the source database).* statement at the beginning of that paragraph

Comment: OK, should I give it try and do some coding ?

Comment: @Franz: I believe the documentation that kobik mentions is either false or misleading. I've used database snapshots with great success - and as far as I can tell, a database snapshot **is** a static, read-only "snapshot" (hence the name!) at a given time. Later changes to the base database don't affect the snapshot. I would go ahead and try using them - I am pretty confident they should work just fine for you